# How do I cut a Pandas dataframe at a certain value in a certain column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data from an experiment from t=0 to t=500s, but I would like to only plot the first 100s of data. How do I "slice" or cut the dataframe so I can plot my interval in matplotlib? Thank you!

used the following

```
x = df.loc[df['ElapsedTime'] == 100]
```

thought it would work, except it ran into a `x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (973088,) and (0, 5)`

Comment: `df.loc[df['ElapsedTime'] <= 100]`, or if one row per timepoint: `df.iloc[:100]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
df.query('ElapsedTime <= 100')
```

?

Comment: it results in the error name 'ElapsedTime' is not defined even though I can plot it

Comment: using backticks for the variable name worked